# "Kernel" vs. "core"

Tags: differences, nouns, plant-physiology

What's the difference between *kernel* and *core*?

The more I look for a difference between both, the more confused I get.

I know both nouns because of IT, but I'm looking for the actual roots in actual English, not technical lingo. It seems to be used for the central fruit parts, but are they interchangeable? Does it depend on which fruit we are talking about?

Comment: Am I the only one who was very confused by this question because I thought it was about the OS kernels and CPU cores?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Kernel" is the soft, edible part of a *nut*. "Kernels" refer specifically [to nuts:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kernel)

> the softer, usually edible part contained in the shell of a nut or the stone of a fruit.
>   the body of a seed within its husk or integuments.

"Core" *for fruits* refers to the central part of a fruit that contains the seeds i.e. The core of an apple e.g. He threw the core of the apple away.

So, basically, "kernel" is used when referring to nuts, and "core" is used when referring to fruits.

Comment: I think the OP was talking about the sofware kernel/core, which although does not render your answer incorrect, but probably asks for an expanded answer. Unless I'm wrong, that is.

Comment: the Op : "...It seems to be used for the central fruit parts, but are they interchangeable? Does it depend on which fruit we are talking about?

Comment: the OP: "...but I'm looking for the actual roots in actual English, not technical lingo

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Great answer, up-voting!

Comment: No prob. mate! :-)

Comment: How does a kernel of corn fit this definition (out of curiosity)?

Comment: My second definition of a kernel: "the body of a seed within its husk or integuments."

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect the most widely recognised *kernel* is that of corn. (This lends weight to Ham and Bacon's above definition.)

Comment: Metaphorically, the *core* is what is central, essential, the *heart* of the matter. The *kernel* is is the germ, the seed, carrying the potential to generate a new whole.

Answer (score 5):

The kernel is the softer, edible part of, for example, a nut, or a seed.
The core is the tough central part of various fruits (e.g. the apple), containing the seeds.

Answer (score 3):

According to Etymonline.com

> **kernel** 
>   O.E. *cyrnel*, from P.Gmc. **kurnilo*- (cf. M.H.G. kornel, M.Du. cornel), from the root of corn "seed, grain" (see *corn*) + -el, dim. suffix. Figurative sense of "core or central part of anything" is from 1550s.

and

> **core** (n.) 
>   late 14c., probably from O.Fr. *coeur* "core of fruit, heart of lettuce," lit. "heart," from L. *cor* "heart," from PIE base **kerd*- "heart" (see heart).

So, to get to the heart of the matter here, the core meaning of kernel is that it is a "core" of something, and "core" comes from a word meaning "heart" — which is another way of referring to the center of something. Nevertheless, *kernel* apparently has its origins in grain, while *core* was used first with fruit. Either way, there is no clear distinction to draw between the two except in IT, where *core* has come to refer to a discrete CPU within a larger CPU cluster, and *kernel* has come to refer to that irreducible piece of core software that comprises an operating system, without which it could not operate.